What's the right way to generate and keep SAML certificates
I'm implementing SSO for a multi-tenant app hosted on AWS.
I've found that self-signed certs work for testing but I'm affraid when I integrate a production server they may required a cert.
Eventually we'll need compliance, so it should be able to publish an x509, decrypt messages coming from the IdP, audit key usage, rotate keys, etc.
I'm confused as to which is the right approach for this? Is there any AWS tool to help with this?
I tried:
self signed but risks not working on production.
AWS KMS provides keys but I have to self sign them.
AWS ACM provides certificates to use on the HTTP layer.

There are two types of certificate in SAML, particularly the WBSSO profile.
The first is the domain certificate. This is for the website domain where the IdP is running, e.g. your.idp.com. This needs to be renewed periodically as it is user facing and is required in order for browsers to trust that your.idp.com is in fact your.idp.com.
The second type is what you refer to. The digital signing certificate in the metadata for IdP. This can be self-signed and very long lived. The reason it can be self-signed is because it is never used by anyone other than the SP and IdP. The SP has the SAML metadata for IdP, which contains the IdP's signing certificate, which it uses to sign the SAMLResponse sent to the SP. The metadata is essentially pre-validated by being accepted by the SP so it knows it can trust everything in the SAML metadata for the IdP. So the IdP's signing certificate can be a very long lived self-signed certificate as it only has to pass trust with the SP, which, by accepting the  IdP's SAML metadata, is saying it trusts everything in it.
There's some information on this in the UK Federation which uses long-lived self-signed signing certificates:
5.1.2 Trust Fabric Certificates
